# Error:The value "System.Object[]" is not of type "prjCustomerService.clsCustomer" and cannot be used in this generic collection. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, sql, wcf

```
public IList<CustomerData> StoredProcedure(int CID)
    {
        IList<CustomerData> lObjEmployees = new List<CustomerData>();
        NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration lObjConfig = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
        lObjConfig.AddAssembly("prjCustomerService");
        NHibernate.ISessionFactory lObjFactory = lObjConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
        NHibernate.ISession lObjSession = lObjFactory.OpenSession();
        NHibernate.IQuery lObjQuery = lObjSession.GetNamedQuery("Test1");
        lObjQuery.SetInt32("CID", @CID);
        IList<clsCustomer> lObjEmpList = lObjQuery.List<clsCustomer>();
        foreach (clsCustomer lObjCurrEmployee in lObjEmpList)
        {
            CustomerData lObjCurrEmpData = new CustomerData();
            lObjCurrEmpData.CID = lObjCurrEmployee.CID;
            lObjCurrEmpData.CName = lObjCurrEmployee.CName;
            lObjCurrEmpData.Cadd = lObjCurrEmployee.CAdd;
            lObjCurrEmpData.Ccontact = lObjCurrEmployee.CContact;
            lObjEmployees.Add(lObjCurrEmpData);
        }
     return lObjEmployees;
    }
```

This is my WCF service code.I get an error at line:

`IList<clsCustomer> lObjEmpList = lObjQuery.List<clsCustomer>();`

> The value "System.Object[]" is not of type "prjCustomerService.clsCustomer" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
>
> Parameter name: value

`Test1` is my stored procedure and it returns a row where `CID="xyz"`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the `alias` that I was using to `select` in the `QueryOver` was different from what I was actually "selecting as":

The Query (notice the `with alias`):

```
IndividualBugViewModel individualBugViewModelAlias = null;

IQueryOver<DomainModel.Models.Bug, DomainModel.Models.Bug> bugQueryOver = Repository
    .QueryOver(() => bugAlias)
    .SelectList(list => list.SelectGroup(() => bugAlias.Details).WithAlias(
                            () => individualBugViewModelAlias.Details)
```

The Result:

```
var bugList = bugQueryOver.List() //Error!
```

Because, when running the query, I was not passing the class type into which the result should be transformed to, it would try to transform the result into type `DomainModel.Models.Bug` instead of `IndividualBugViewModel`. This resulted into the error.

So I changed it to:

```
var bugList = bugQueryOver.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<IndividualBugViewModel>())
                 .List<IndividualBugViewModel>();
```

In your case, the `<return class="className">` in your `named query` must be incompatible with `clsCustomer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
IList<clsCustomer> lObjEmpList = lObjQuery.OfType<clsCustomer>.ToList();
```

Remember to add `using System.Linq` to your using statements.

With this statement your say that your non-generic IQuery must be filtered to contain only `clsCustomer` objects, then with .ToList you say that you want to create a list out of it.